# A Different version of facility location problem

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, approximation

[image: Facility Location Problem]

I posted this question before but since Mathjax is not supported here, I took a picture of the compiled latex file and I am posting a picture of that.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit for this question.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I don't want to crosspost the same question. Maybe if I don't get any answers here, I will delete the post and ask there. Also, I guess the question is readable now.

Comment: Are the points in 2d or 3d Euclidean space?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate an issue, which is clearly not the case here.

Comment: @Dave Just like the Facility location problem, let's say all the points are in a metric space(2d or 3d are just special cases), where the distance function is symmetric and satisfies the triangle inequality. For this general problem, we already know a 4-approx in the harder case as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: The algorithm cost is less, which is good, but the optimal cost is less too, which is a problem. Agree that this does not belong on Stack Overflow (and I am an [algorithm] maximalist.)